# Error: INSERT INTO trabajadores VALUES ('Luis', 'Rad','16'). Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php

Estoy estudiando programación y estoy creando dos archivos. Uno es el formulario donde se introducen los datos y otro archivo que los recoge para guardarlos en la base de datos *MySQL*. *Estoy trabajando en local*.

El caso es que al cumplimentar el formulario y enviarlo me da error. He creado la base de datos desde phpAdmin como "empleados" con la tabla "trabajadores" y los campos "Nombre" "Apellidos" y "Edad". La conexión a la base de datos es como localhost, user, contraseña 1234 y el nombre de la base de datos. En la base de datos he creado en la tabla "trabajadores" 4 campos: Nombre, Apellidos, Edad y el primer campo un id autoincrementable.

He tenido que cambiar el nombre de la base de datos que había puesto anteriormente a "empleados". De esta manera cambio el fichero procesar.php, anteriormente no había puesto clave porque es un servidor de pruebas en el propio pc. El error que me aparece en el mensaje:

> Error: INSERT INTO trabajadores VALUES ('Luis', 'Rad','16'). Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Cambie la línea que me indicaste anteriormente, pero igualmente da error:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO trabajadores  VALUES ('".$Nombre."',  
        '".$Apellidos."','".$Edad."')";
```

He introducido a modo de prueba el nombre Luis Rad de 16 años.

El código de los dos archivos:

**Código del formulario**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="es">
    <head> 
        <title>Formulario</title> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <center>
            <form action="ejecutar.php" method="post">
                <p> 
                    <label for="Nombre">Nombre</label> 
                    <input type="text" name="Nombre" id="Nombre"> 
                </p>
                <p> 
                    <label for="Apellidos">Apellidos:</label> 
                    <input type="text" name="Apellidos" id="Apellidos"> 
                </p>
                <p> 
                    <label for="Edad">Edad</label> 
                    <input type="number" name="Edad" id="Edad"> 
                </p>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
            </form> 
        </center> 
    </body>
</html>
```

**Archivo que recoge los datos del formulario ejecutar.php:**

```
<head> 
    <title>insercción de datos</title> 
</head> 
  
<body> 
    <center> 
        <?php
        /* datos de conexión con la base de datos */
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "1234", "empleados"); 
          
        /* revisamos la conexión */
        if($conn === false){ 
            die("Error: No es posible la conexión. " 
                . mysqli_connect_error()); 
        } 
          
        /* Tomamos los valores del formulario */
        $Nombre =  $_REQUEST['Nombre']; 
        $Apellidos = $_REQUEST['Apellidos']; 
        $Edad =  $_REQUEST['Edad'];  
          
       
        /* insertamos los datos a la db empleados de la tabla trabajadores */
        $sql = "INSERT INTO trabajadores  VALUES ('".$Nombre."',  
            '".$Apellidos."','".$Edad."')"; 
          
        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){ 
            echo "<h3>Datos recibidos correctamente";  
        } else{ 
            echo "Error: $sql. " 
                . mysqli_error($conn); 
        } 
          
        /* Cerramos la conexión */
        mysqli_close($conn); 
        ?> 
    </center> 
</body>
</html>
```

Aquí te dejo una captura de la estructura de la tabla

[image: captura de phpAdmin]

Comment: ¿Qué error da? Pulsa en [edit] y agrega el mensaje de error completo, como texto.

Comment: Si en la consulta solo especificas valores, omitiendo lista de campos, entonces debes colocar todas las columnas de la tabla en el orden en que se crearon. Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar mensaje de error completo y estructura de la tabla.

Comment: Cuando haces insert into xxx values (1,2,3), sin indicar en el insert a qué campos insertar, asume que el insert va a usar **todos** los campos de la tabla. Si no estás poniendo datos para todos los campos que no tienen default value, va a fallar como está fallando. Como no nos has mostrado cuál es la estructura de la tabla, no tenemos cómo decirte cuál es la consulta correcta

Comment: La columna ID es autoincrementable, puedes pasar un valor nulo, por ejemplo: `$sql = "INSERT INTO trabajadores  VALUES (null, '$Nombre', '$Apellidos', '$Edad')";`. Ahora el problema es que tu código es vulnerable a inyecciones SQL, lo mejor es usar [consultas preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) para evitar errores y ataques.

Comment: Ahora si esta funcionando bien. Si sobre la vulnerabilidad hay que mejorar la seguridad. Muchas gracias. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Los `INSERT` que no mencionan de forma explícita los nombres de columna son una pésima práctica, por varios motivos, algunos muy graves.

Consideremos tu `INSERT` actual, corregido con un valor `NULL` para la columna ID:

```
INSERT INTO trabajadores VALUES (NULL,'Luis', 'Rad','16');
```

Ese INSERT funcionará sin problema mientras tu tabla tenga las columnas en este orden:

```
id
nombre
apellido
edad
```

**PERO**, ¿qué pasa si mañana, por algún motivo, **el orden de las columnas cambia en la tabla**, viniendo a ser algo así?:

```
id
apellido
nombre
edad
```

¿Adivinas lo catastrófico que será tu INSERT en lo adelante? Lo que ocurrirá es que el valor que era para `nombre` se guardará en `apellido` y viceversa.

O, imaginemos que **tu aplicación evoluciona**, y se decide agregar **una nueva columna a la tabla**:

```
id
nombre
apellido
edad
nuevaColumna
```

El código empezará a fallar, porque tu INSERT no toma en cuenta un valor para `nuevaColumna`. Si para mayor complicación, tu INSERT se encuentra en cientos de archivos, en una aplicación más o menos grande... te quiero ver averiguando donde rayos escribiste ese código para corregirlo.

La recomendación por tanto, y que es a la vez la solución a este error, es que **escribas siempre de forma explícita los nombres de columna en las sentencias `INSERT`**, sabiendo que para las columnas autoincrement puedes pasar el valor `NULL`.

El código quedaría así:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO trabajadores  (id, Nombre, Apellidos, Edad) 
            VALUES (NULL, '$Nombre', '$Apellidos', '$Edad')";
```

De ese modo, cada valor se insertará **siempre** en la columna indicada de forma explícita, y si la tabla evoluciona el código no será erróneo, mientras te adaptas a la evolución.

Nótese además que he simplificado la sintaxis. En PHP puedes usar variables y comillas simples dentro de comillas dobles sin problemas. El código queda más claro así que concatenando con el punto.

Por último:

- los campos del tipo `Edad` no deberían guardarse en la base de datos. Luis, nacido el 1 de marzo, tendrá 17 años el próximo lunes. ¿De qué modo vas a actualizar la información? Debiste haber recogido su fecha de nacimiento, y calcular la edad, allí donde la necesites (por código) a partir de ese dato.
- tu código es vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Como ya algunos compañeros te han señalado, considera usar **consultas preparadas** para blindarlo contra este tipo de ataques.

Comment: Tengo que estudiar bien las consultas preparadas (estoy aprendiendo y adquiriendo conocimientos). Muy bien explicado paso a paso tus explicaciones, muchas gracias.  No obstante esta aplicación para trabajar en local me imagino que no supondría peligro, sería en todo caso si esta alojada en una página web, ¿sería correcto?

Comment: @Luis Si la aplicación **está destinada al uso de terceros** (si es en local o en remoto poco importa), deberías usar consultas preparadas. Supongamos un uso local donde hay varios niveles de usuarios. Si no usas consultas preparadas un usuario de nivel inferior podría escribir consultas para obtener información que le estaría vetada, o podría falsear información en niveles de acceso a los que no podría entrar por otros medios. Es sólo un ejemplo, porque la inyección SQL, según qué contextos, podría tener un alcance enorme, hasta llegar al mismo sistema de archivos.

Answer (score 0):

el primer error es usar el root de mysql y sin clave, funciona pero es una pesima practica

luego en tu código, prueba cambiar esto :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO alumnos  VALUES ('".$Nombre."',  
            '".$Apellidos."','".$Edad."')";
```

Comment: Porque dices que es "pesima practica" usar root? Ademas su estructura del `insert` esta bien y es mas limpia. Por otro lado el OP debe colocar el error que le genera, asumes que esta mal insert pero no es asi

Comment: porque asi es como despues te hackean las aplicaciones en la web

Comment: Obviamente se cambian las credenciales cuando se trabaja ya en produccion, pero en este caso el OP esta trabajando "localmente"(localhost) por lo cual no es necesario cambiarlo, ten en cuenta lo que dije al final de mi primer comentario

Answer (score 0):

El error es porque tienes en 4 columnas pero solo le estas enviando valores a 3. Para resolverlo lo que puedes hacer es especificar las columnas que vas a enviarle algún parametro.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO trabajadores(Nombre, Apellidos, Edad)  
VALUES ('".$Nombre."','".$Apellidos."','".$Edad."')";
```