# Que valor poner cuando la columna es autoincrementable mysql desde java

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

estoy creando un programa en java que se conecta a mysql 8.0.23 y utilizo netbeans. Soy nuevo programando aclaro.

```
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO clientes VALUES('auto_increment',"+tfNombre.getText()+"','"+tfApellido.getText()+"','"+tfCel.getText()+"','"+tfDomicilio.getText()+"','"+tfCiudad.getText()+"','"+tfDni.getText()+"','"+tfNotas.getText()+"')");
```

Estoy insertando esos datos, y la primera columna que dice 'auto_increment' creo que es el problema(lo puse para probarlo), ya que la columna se llama **Id** y la configure con phpmyadmin para que se autoincrementable. No se que valor poner ahi para que de un valor **Id** en la columna **Id**, ya intente con **NULL** **null**, **0**, etc. El problema es que me da el siguiente error, y no se que valor poner el el codigo para que incremente el valor en 1. del ultimo que estaba en la columna.

> ava.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '',' asdsad',' 3121','asdasd','adasd','21231','asadsad')' at line 1
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdateInternal(StatementImpl.java:1333)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeLargeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:2106)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1243)
> at serviciotecnico.Registro.jButton2ActionPerformed(Registro.java:220)
> at serviciotecnico.Registro.access$100(Registro.java:20)
> at serviciotecnico.Registro$2.actionPerformed(Registro.java:117)
> at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
> at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
> at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
> at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
> at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
> at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
> at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
> at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)

> Cita en bloque

Comment: Puedes mostrar la estructura de la tabla? tiene habilitado el auto increment en la tabla? en el insert que eestas enviando no debería ir ese 'auto_increment' ya que en MySQLal habilitar la opción el por defecto hará el trabajo.

Comment: Puedes poner `NULL`  (o sea `NULL` en cuanto valor, no la cadena `"NULL"` ) o puedes omitir esa columna en la instrucción de inserción, evitando así la **mala práctica** de no usar nombres de columnas de forma explícita en tus instrucciones SQL. Al ser auto-increment, se incrementará sola, por supuesto.

Comment: [En esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/431515/29967) he dado algunos motivos por los que nunca deberías escribir consultas INSERT sin poner de forma explícita los nombres de columna. Allí hay un ejemplo de inserción precisamente usando la columna `id` que es auto-increment. Aunque allí era en PHP el concepto es el mismo.

Comment: `"INSERT INTO clientes VALUES(null,"`. Con el exhorto a usar columnas nombradas y sentencias preparadas.

Comment: Bueno gracias a todos la verdad que lei a todos y me di cuenta que muchos me indicaban que poniendo NULL lo solucionaba y era cierto, pero tambien sin utilizar NULL como me indico el usuario Jorgesys tambien pude solucionarlo.

Mi erraro estaba en que me faltaba una comilla simple ' en donde agregaba "+tfNombre.getText()+"' me faltaba iniciar la comilla simple '. 

Desde ya muchas gracias porque he aprendido como utilizar bien esta funcion mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para definir tu campo id como auto incrementable debes definirlo al crear tu tabla, como en este ejemplo el campo `id` es auto incrementable:

```
CREATE TABLE personas (
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     nombre CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     apellido CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     edad INT
);
```

lo importante aquì es que al definir el campo como incrementable no necesitas tratar de insertarlo, ejemplos:

```
INSERT INTO personas (nombre,apellido,edad) VALUES('Cesar', 'Barbosa', 22);
INSERT INTO personas (nombre,apellido,edad) VALUES('Jorge', 'sys', 31);
```

el valor de `id` automàticamente serà un valor incrementado en 1, por lo tanto no necesitas definir un valor en este campo, solo define actualizar los demàs campos.

Revisa la documentaciòn:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Otro problema que tienes es que si tienes campos de tipo CHAR debes usar el como contenedor las comillas simples (`'`) y en este punto falta la del lado izquierdo:

```
... ,"+tfNombre.getText()+"', ...
```

deberìa ser:

```
... ,'"+tfNombre.getText()+"', ...
```

---

Recuerda que no es recomendable usar [palabras reservadas](https://documentation.help/MySQL-5.0-es/ch09s06.html) como nombres o valores de campos, te lo comento por el valor "auto_increment".

Como comenta @A.Cedano debes tambièn preparar tus querys (consultas) para evitar la inyecciòn SQL, revisa:

[¿Qué es la inyección SQL y cómo puedo evitarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10518/qu%C3%A9-es-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-y-c%C3%B3mo-puedo-evitarla)

Comment: Y, debería usar consultas preparadas para blindar el código contra ataques de *Inyección SQL*.

Comment: Muy cierto @A.Cedano , muchas gracias, actualicè la respuesta con un articulo de Alvaro Montoro con lo que comentas.

Comment: Muchas gracias Jorgesys, al leer todos los comentario pude darme cuenta que faltaba ese ' simple y era el error de todo, igualmente probé utilizando NULL sin comillas y funciono el ingreso de datos, pero como me dijiste que podía obviarlo lo deje directamente sin NULL. Desde ya muchas gracias.