# Insert en mysql usando php

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy realizando el siguiente insert pero no esta guardando el valor, cual podria ser el error? La conexion a la BD ta comprobe que funciona

```
<?php
    $materia1 = $_POST['materia1'];
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "inscripciones");
    
    if ($materia1 === "on") {
        $inscripcion = mysqli_query($con,'INSERT INTO tbl_inscripcion VALUES ("",1,"materia 1")');
    }
    if (!$inscripcion) {
        echo "Error al guardar";
    }else{
        echo "Incripcion Realizada Exitosamente.";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Cuál es la estructura de la tabla `tbl_inscripcion`?

Comment: ¿La primera columna es numérica y/o de autoincremento? Entonces el primer valor debería ser `NULL` en vez de `""`. O podrías especificar columnas y valores, omitiendo las que no son necesarias, porque pueden tener valor predefinido, nulo o de autoincremento: `INSERT INTO tbl_inscripcion (campo2, campo3) VALUES (1, 'Materia 1')`

Comment: Escribir consultas INSERT con nombres de columna implícitos es bastante cómodo, pero es una **pésima práctica**, [aquí explico algunos motivos con ejemplos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/431515/29967). Dicho eso, tu consulta puede fallar por varios motivos: error de sintaxis, violación de alguna restricción (PK o UNIQUE duplicada, de integridad referencial, etc). Intenta mostrar el error en el último `if` para saber por qué está fallando el código.

Answer (score 0):

Para saber el error tienes que capturarlo y mostrarlo, de otro modo solo vas a estar adivinando que puede estar mal:

```
<?php
    $materia1 = $_POST['materia1'];
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "inscripciones");
    
    if ($materia1 === "on") {
        $inscripcion = mysqli_query($con,'INSERT INTO tbl_inscripcion VALUES ("",1,"materia 1")');
    }
    if (!$inscripcion) {
        echo "Error al guardar :" . mysqli_error($con);;
    }else{
        echo "Incripcion Realizada Exitosamente.";
    }
```