# al ingresar la información desde el formulario el registro me parece exitoso, pero no me aparece en la base de datos MySQL

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin, localhost

conecta bien la base de datos y aunque hace el intento no aparecen los datos en la tabla y la verdad no se la razón adjunto el código. Me muestra como si el registro se inserto exitosamente pero cuando miro la base de datos, en la tabla no sale nada

````
<?php

$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","clinica_anfr") ;

$bd= mysqli_select_db($conexion,"clinica_anfr") ;

?php
error_reporting(5);
require 'conex.php';

$id_cedulas=$_POST["id_cedulas"];
$administradores_doctores=$_POST["administradores_doctores"];
$id_cedulas=$_POST['id_cedulas'];
$nombres=$_POST['nombres'];
$apellidos=$_POST['apellidos'];
$direccion=$_POST['direccion'];
$telefono=$_POST['telefono'];
$seguridad_social=$_POST['seguridad_social'];
$citas_horarios=$_POST['citas_horarios'];
$Asistio=$_POST['Asistio'];
$no_asistio=$_POST['no_asistio'];
$doctor_atiende=$_POST['doctor_atiende'];
$novedades=$_POST['novedades'];

$sql= "INSERT INTO agenda VALUES ('$id_cedulas','$administradores_doctores','$id_cedulas','$nombres','$apellidos','$direccion','$seguridad_socia','$citas_horarios','$$Asistio','$no_asistio','$doctor_atiende','$novedades')";
$query = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql,$insertar);
if($query){
echo 'eror al registrar';
}
else {
echo' registro exitoso';
}

mysqli_close($conexion); ```
````

Comment: ¿Por qué pasas tres parámetros a la función: `mysqli_query($conexion,$sql,$insertar)`? ¿Qué representa ahí `$insertar`? Además, para verificar que efectivamente se insertaron filas deberías usar [`affected_rows`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.affected-rows.php).

Comment: Revisa la respuesta que he dado más abajo y el código propuesto, haz esos cambios y dime si funciona.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y agrega aquí toda la información requerida para poder ayudarte: código actual, mensaje de error y estructura de la tabla en la que quieres insertar. No entiendo qué significan los enlaces de tus últimos comentarios, ni qué tienen que ver con el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Hay varios errores en tu código.

Empecemos por un error que te lleva a una gran confusión:

```
if($query){
echo 'eror al registrar';
}
else {
echo' registro exitoso';
}
```

En ese bloque le estás diciendo al código: *si `$query` es `true` imprime que hubo un error, de lo contrario, imprime que el registro fue exitoso*.

Debería ser lo contrario, puesto que cuando `$query` sea `true` significa que no hubo error.

Más cosas...

1. Estás pasando un tercer parámetro a `mysqli_query`. ¿De dónde sacas ese parámetro? Esta función admitiría un tercer parámetro si quieres setear el result mode, pero esto no tendría sentido aquí.
2. En la conexión ya estás eligiendo la base de datos (cuarto parámetro) por lo que esto es redundante: `$bd= mysqli_select_db($conexion,"clinica_anfr");`
3. La única forma segura de verificar que ocurrió una inserción es verificando con [`affected_rows()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.affected-rows.php), esta propiedad te devolverá el total de filas afectadas en consultas de tipo INSERT, UPDATE o DELETE.
4. **Tu sentencia `INSERT` será errónea**.

   Por un lado, estás usando lo que se conoce como INSERT implícito (no mencionas explícitamente las columnas en la sentencia), eso significa que deberás aportar valores para todas las columnas en su orden. Por ejemplo, no estás indicando ningún valor para la primera columna de la tabla que es `id_informe`. Me dirás: *pero esa columna no necesita valor, es auto-incremental*. Es cierto, pero al usar un INSERT implícito debes aportar un valor para ella (`null` en este caso), porque el INSERT escrito como lo tienes buscará un valor **para todas las columnas de la tabla**. Por este motivo no se recomiendan nunca los INSERT implícitos, y por otros motivos [explicados aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/431515/29967).

   Por otro lado, según la estructura de la tabla que muestras hay 14 columnas, pero tú estás mandando valores para 12 columnas (asumiendo que mandaremos `null`  a la columna auto-incremental, falta un valor).

   ADEMÁS, has puesto dos `$$` en la variable `$$Asistio`, para evitar este tipo de líos en el código que pueden hacerte perder horas y hasta días, te recomiendo que escribas tus consultas indentadas, así podrás comparar si falta algo más fácilmente y detectar errores como la doble `$$` ... Al organizar el código, vemos rápidamente que no escribiste un valor para la columna `telefono` y, llama la atención que mandes el mismo valor para dos columnas (me refiero a `$id_cedula`), tú veras...

Tu código, corregido y mejorado, quedaría así:

```
<?php

$conexion=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","","clinica_anfr") ;
error_reporting(5);
require 'conex.php';

$id_cedulas=$_POST["id_cedulas"];
$administradores_doctores=$_POST["administradores_doctores"];
$nombres=$_POST['nombres'];
$apellidos=$_POST['apellidos'];
$direccion=$_POST['direccion'];
$telefono=$_POST['telefono'];
$seguridad_social=$_POST['seguridad_social'];
$citas_horarios=$_POST['citas_horarios'];
$Asistio=$_POST['Asistio'];
$no_asistio=$_POST['no_asistio'];
$doctor_atiende=$_POST['doctor_atiende'];
$novedades=$_POST['novedades'];
$sql= "INSERT INTO agenda 
VALUES (
  null,
  '$id_cedulas',
  '$administradores_doctores',
  '$id_cedulas',
  '$nombres',
  '$apellidos',
  '$direccion',
  '$telefono',
  '$seguridad_socia',
  '$citas_horarios',
  '$Asistio',
  '$no_asistio',
  '$doctor_atiende',
  '$novedades'
)";



if ( mysqli_query($conexion,$sql) && mysqli_affected_rows($conexion) > 0 ) 
{
    echo 'registro exitoso';
}
else 
{
    echo 'error al registrar '.mysqli_error($conexion); #Sólo para depurar, quita luego la parte de mysqli_error
}

mysqli_close($conexion);
```

**Post-Data:**

Aún falta dar seguridad a tu código implementando consultas preparadas, pues el código actual es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*.

Comment: OK, hay más errores viendo la estructura de la tabla, ahora edito.

Comment: @duverneyrobayo revisa la respuesta editada, tienes un grave error en tu forma de escribir el INSERT, lee todo de nuevo e implementa el nuevo código. Copia y pega todo el bloque para no cometer errores y me dices el resultado, he agregado una salida usando `mysqli_error` sólo para fase de depuración, la quitas cuando el código funcione.

Comment: Será que estás verificando en otra base de datos o en otra tabla, si te sale exitoso con ese código es porque el registro se insertó. ¿Puedes agregar a la pregunta una captura de pantalla de la base de datos, @Duverrobayo?

Comment: por favor revise este link    https://we.tl/t-fpSaUrwYxn   ,    son imagenes enviadas por weptransfer